# How to Create Relationship between city and Location in Laravel 6?

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-6.2

I have 2 tables in my database with cities and states, If i am submitting cities then i want to save state_id in my cities table.
Primary key for cities table is ctId
Primary key for cities table is stId

Here are my State Model...
State.php file

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\City;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class State extends Model
 {
protected $primaryKey = 'stId';
// protected $gaurded = [];
public function cities(){
    return $this->hasMany(City::class,'ctId','ctId');
 }
 }
```

Here are my City Model...
City.php file

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\State;
class City extends Model
{

protected $primaryKey = 'ctId';
protected $gaurded = [];

public function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
}
```

Here are my CityController.php

```
    public function store(Request $r){
    //dd($r->all());
    $cities=new City;
    $cities->name=$r->cityname;
    $cities->slug=$r->cityslug;
    $cities->save();
    $this->return()->back();
}
```

But when I am submitting this for, I am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'stId' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: and what would specify what state that city belongs to in your `store` method?

Comment: you  are not storing state id

Comment: change relationship method in State Model: `return $this->hasMany(City::class,'stId','stId');` and in store method in controller save stId field.

Comment: Thank You so much Jinak Somaiya, I was mistaking in stId.